# Default permission on new files

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

Ok, so I know that this question has been asked a million times, but it seems that using the solutions from questions like this has not helped me so far.

**How do I set default permissions for new files uploaded through vsftpd?**

As of now the files will get the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi      7 Jun 28 13:21 FILENAME
```

But I need the file to be executable. I could manually chmod the files, but that would not include files in the future.
What i have tried:

1. Setting umask in login.defs - Even after a restart, if I then type umask I will get umask 0022 (not what I set)
2. Setting local_umask=022 and file_open_mode=0644 in /etc/vsftpd.conf

Does anyone have a solution for this? The permissions for future files should be somewhat like:

> -rwxr--r--

Hope you understand. I'm new on linux.

Comment: Did you restart the `vsftpd` daemon after you changed the configuration file?

Comment: Yes, even tried a reboot.

Comment: Umm…, you tried setting `file_open_mode=0644`?  Why not `0744`, which is what you want?